# AutoGPT - unable to initiate python (Ubuntu / Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, autogpt

when I try initiating, I seem to get this error message, can you please assist:

```
omz@omz-ND-3A78:~/Auto-GPT$ python3 -m autogpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    autogpt.cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1114, in invoke
    return Command.invoke(self, ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/cli.py", line 87, in main
    from autogpt.main import run_auto_gpt
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from autogpt.agent.agent import Agent
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/agent/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from autogpt.agent.agent import Agent
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/agent/agent.py", line 5, in <module>
    from autogpt.app import execute_command, get_command
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from autogpt.agent.agent_manager import AgentManager
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/agent/agent_manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from autogpt.llm import Message, create_chat_completion
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/llm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from autogpt.llm.api_manager import ApiManager
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/llm/api_manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from autogpt.logs import logger
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/logs.py", line 14, in <module>
    from autogpt.speech import say_text
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/speech/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from autogpt.speech.say import say_text
  File "/home/omz/Auto-GPT/autogpt/speech/say.py", line 34, in <module>
    def _get_voice_engine(config: Config) -> tuple[VoiceBase, VoiceBase]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I am not sure what the issue is? I have both python3.8 and python3.11 installed

I thought the issue might be that the wrong version of python is defaluted when I use `python3 -m autogpt`.

Comment: Have you tried this script in the files of AutoGPT - scripts/main.py? [This website](https://lablab.ai/t/autogpt-tutorial-how-to-set-up-your-own-ai-bot-in-under-30-minutes) uses it to initialize AutoGPT.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.